# Magento Partial Shipments

Tags: shipping, order-status, order-state

Is there any way to manage partial shipments within magento?

Scenario: - I have a customer that order some items ( some of which would be back ordered ) - I want to ship him items that I have in stock and instead of having the order marked as Complete, possibly have it marked as Partially Shipped

Any way of possibly going about that ?

Side note: I use a program called Acctivate for order processing and invoicing, which automatically sends the shipping information and whats back ordered and what not, however whenever even a partial shipment is shipped, magento simply marks it complete and lists all products on the order as shipping, which is also not working as intended.

Comment: Any progress on this or issues with Acctivate inventory sync skipping SKUs?

Comment: Not as of yet, we had an open support request which ended up resolving to their development team looking into and working on it, and then subsequently having the request closed. I just reopened asking whether there has been any new developments in the issue. :)